# Can't open socket im systemd service

Tags: debian, permissions, systemd, socket

I have a software written in C language which opens a UDP socket to my server through internet.

I use a systemd service approach to run the code at startup. It works fine. But in some cases which I use it in some networks (specially an organization or company network), code runs at OS startup but it can't open socket. When I manually stop and start it using `systemctl` command in root access all things is OK.

I put a delay in the code, but the issue still exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Stewart thinks right. I added this in my service file:

```
After=syslog.target network.target sockets.target network-online.target multi-user.target
```

It causes to the service starts later and the issue is resolves.

Comment: I think multi-user.target element plays the main rule.

Answer (score 0):

If your program fails to open a UDP socket when started with systemd, it sounds like it is started too early.  Make sure the network is up before starting this service.

You can do that by adding this to your service file:

```
[Unit]
After=network.target
```

Comment: you are right, but your recommendation couldn't solve the issue. I will tell the solution in a new post. thank you.